# How to use nested modules with a leaflet map

Tags: r, shiny, shinymodules

I am trying to use `shiny` modules to build an App with a `leaflet` map. However, when I run the code below the map does not render properly -- it is greyed out.

What I would like to happen is that the *user* selects the city from the side panel and the relevant section of map is shown (there is an example at the end of the question using standard shiny to illustrate).

I think it may be that the user input is not getting correctly passed between modules but do not know how to fix it. And indeed if I change the relevant bit to hard code the city `setView(lng = data[data$pt == "London", "lng"], lat = data[data$pt == "London", "lat"], zoom = 9)` then the map renders.

Any hints on how to do this with modules please?
This is my non-working attempt using modules:

```
# Some data
data <- data.frame(pt = c("London", "Manchester"), lat=c(51.5, 53.48), lng=c(0.126, -2.24))
  
# Define the side panel UI and server      
sideUI <- function(id) {
                        ns <- NS(id)
                        selectInput(ns("city"), "", choices=data$pt, selected = "London")
                       }

# In this case this server not needed but using uiOuput/renderUI in real case
# sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) { })}
         
# Define the UI and server functions for the map
mapUI <- function(id) {
                    ns <- NS(id)
                    leafletOutput(ns("map"))
                    }    
    
mapServer <- function(id) {
                            moduleServer(
                                id,
                                function(input, output, session) {
                                    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
                                                leaflet() %>%
                                                    addTiles() %>%
                                                    setView(lng = data[data$pt == input$city, "lng"], 
                                                            lat = data[data$pt == input$city, "lat"], 
                                                            zoom = 9) 
                                                    })
                                    })
                                }
    
# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
              dashboardHeader(),
              dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
              dashboardBody(mapUI("mapUK"))
          ) 
server <- function(input, output, session) { mapServer("mapUK") }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This is a working example using standard shiny functions which shows what I am trying to do

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
ui <- dashboardPage(
              dashboardHeader(),
              dashboardSidebar(selectInput("city", "", choices=data$pt, selected = "London")),
              dashboardBody(leafletOutput("map"))) 
    
server <- function(input, output, session) { 
                output$map <- renderLeaflet({
                                            leaflet() %>%
                                                addTiles() %>%
                                                setView(lng = data[data$pt == input$city, "lng"],
                                                        lat = data[data$pt == input$city, "lat"], 
                                                        zoom = 9) 
                                                })
                                    }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: input$city does not work inside the namespace "mapUK" since it belongs to "side"

Comment: @mnist ; yes that look like it. Do you know how to pass this input info between modules?

Comment: why would you put them in two modules anyway if one does contain UI only?

Comment: Because it is a very large App. Also one UI is for the side panel and the other for the main body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass inputs from one module to another, one must return them from the source and use them in the target as an argument.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)

# Some data
data <- data.frame(pt = c("London", "Manchester"), lat=c(51.5, 53.48), lng=c(0.126, -2.24))

# Define the side panel UI and server
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  selectInput(ns("city"), "", choices=data$pt, selected = "London")
}

sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      # define a reactive and return it
      city_r <- reactiveVal()
      observeEvent(input$city, {
        city_r(input$city)
      })

      return(city_r)
    })
}
# In this case this server not needed but using uiOuput/renderUI in real case
# sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) { })}

# Define the UI and server functions for the map
mapUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  leafletOutput(ns("map"))
}

mapServer <- function(id, city) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          setView(lng = data[data$pt == city(), "lng"],
                  lat = data[data$pt == city(), "lat"],
                  zoom = 9)
      })
    })
}

# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
  dashboardBody(mapUI("mapUK"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # use the reactive in another module
  city_input <- sideServer("side")
  mapServer("mapUK", city_input)

  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Excellent thank you. I saw a similar example at https://thatdatatho.com/communicating-shiny-modules-simple-example/ but just couldn't get it to work. Thanks again.

Comment: From link ^^, `sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) { reactive(input$city) })}` also works. It seems the primary issue was I named the second argument of `mapServer` as `input` which messed everything up.