# Shiny widget that is dependent on other shiny widget does not work in shiny modularized app

Tags: r, shiny, module

In the shiny app below I use shiny modules to create a leaflet map. The issue is that the one of the 2 widgets that interact with the map is dependent on the other so I need to use uiOutput() for them but I do not think that they communicate well since the dataset that they should have created is not created.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# Some data
data<-structure(list(scientificName = c("Turdus merula Linnaeus, 1758", 
                                        "Passer domesticus (Linnaeus, 1758)", "Cantharellus cinereus (Pers.) Fr.", 
                                        "Flammulina fennae Bas", "Mycena crocata (Schrad.) P.Kumm.", 
                                        "Lepista luscina (Fr.) Singer", "Mycena permixta (Britzelm.) Sacc.", 
                                        "Rhodophyllus byssisedus (Pers.) Quel.", "Rhodophyllus porphyrophaeus (Fr.) J.E.Lange", 
                                        "Panaeolus rickenii Hora"), decimalLatitude = c(52.204429, 51.387818, 
                                                                                        52.176667, 50.066111, 49.179167, 49.419444, 52.3, 52.3, 49.419444, 
                                                                                        49.179167), decimalLongitude = c(21.189275, 19.62673, 19.088056, 
                                                                                                                         19.502778, 22.434722, 20.380556, 20.566667, 20.566667, 20.380556, 
                                                                                                                         22.434722)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
                                                                                                                                                    41L, 42L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                    ))
data$year<-c(1990,1989,2003,1990,1980,1990,1989,2003,1990,1980)
# Define the side panel UI and server
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    uiOutput("ye"),
    uiOutput("scient"),
    actionButton(ns("action"),"Submit")
  )
  
}

sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      # define a reactive and return it
      react<-eventReactive(input$action,{
        
        omited <-subset(data, data$scientificName %in% isolate(input$sci))
      })
      
      return(react)
      
    })
}
# In this case this server not needed but using uiOuput/renderUI in real case
# sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) { })}

# Define the UI and server functions for the map
mapUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    leafletOutput(ns("map"))
  )
}

mapServer <- function(id, city) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$map<-renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet(data = city()) %>% addTiles() %>%
          addMarkers(~decimalLatitude, ~decimalLongitude, popup = ~as.character(scientificName), label = ~as.character(scientificName))
      })
    })
}

# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
  dashboardBody(mapUI("mapUK"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ye<-renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "yea",
      label = "Year", 
      choices = sort(unique(data$year),decreasing=F),
      selected = unique(data$year),
      multiple = T
      
    )
  })
  output$scient<-renderUI({
    data <-subset(data, data$year %in% input$yea)
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "sci",
      label = "Scientific name", 
      choices = unique(data$scientificName),
      selected = unique(data$scientificName)[1], 
      
    )
  })
  # use the reactive in another module
  city_input <- sideServer("side")
  mapServer("mapUK", city_input)
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is improved version:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

# Some data
data<-structure(list(scientificName = c("Turdus merula Linnaeus, 1758", 
                                        "Passer domesticus (Linnaeus, 1758)", "Cantharellus cinereus (Pers.) Fr.", 
                                        "Flammulina fennae Bas", "Mycena crocata (Schrad.) P.Kumm.", 
                                        "Lepista luscina (Fr.) Singer", "Mycena permixta (Britzelm.) Sacc.", 
                                        "Rhodophyllus byssisedus (Pers.) Quel.", "Rhodophyllus porphyrophaeus (Fr.) J.E.Lange", 
                                        "Panaeolus rickenii Hora"), decimalLatitude = c(52.204429, 51.387818, 
                                                                                        52.176667, 50.066111, 49.179167, 49.419444, 52.3, 52.3, 49.419444, 
                                                                                        49.179167), decimalLongitude = c(21.189275, 19.62673, 19.088056, 
                                                                                                                         19.502778, 22.434722, 20.380556, 20.566667, 20.566667, 20.380556, 
                                                                                                                         22.434722)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
                                                                                                                                                    41L, 42L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                                                    ))
data$year<-c(1990,1989,2003,1990,1980,1990,1989,2003,1990,1980)
# Define the side panel UI and server
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    
    uiOutput(ns("ye")),
    uiOutput(ns("scient")),
    actionButton(ns("action"),"Submit")
  )
  
}

sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      # define a reactive and return it
      react<-eventReactive(input$action,{
        
        omited <-subset(data, data$scientificName %in% isolate(input$sci))
      })
      
      output$ye<-renderUI({
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("yea"),
          label = "Year", 
          choices = sort(unique(data$year),decreasing=F),
          selected = unique(data$year),
          multiple = T
          
        )
      })
      
      output$scient<-renderUI({
        data <-subset(data, data$year %in% input$yea)
        
        pickerInput(
          inputId = session$ns("sci"),
          label = "Scientific name", 
          choices = unique(data$scientificName),
          selected = unique(data$scientificName)[1], 
          
        )
      })
      
      return(react)
      
    })
}
# In this case this server not needed but using uiOuput/renderUI in real case
# sideServer <- function(id) { moduleServer(id,function(input, output, session) { })}

# Define the UI and server functions for the map
mapUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    leafletOutput(ns("map"))
  )
}

mapServer <- function(id, city) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$map<-renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet(data = city()) %>% addTiles() %>%
          addMarkers(~decimalLatitude, ~decimalLongitude, popup = ~as.character(scientificName), label = ~as.character(scientificName))
      })
    })
}

# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
  dashboardBody(mapUI("mapUK"))
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # use the reactive in another module
  city_input <- sideServer("side")
  mapServer("mapUK", city_input)
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I have changed:

1. ui and server in module should be connected - I mean, you should use `renderUI` insider server in module (if `uiOutput` is in ui in module), not in `server` from `app.R`. I moved them.
2. You forgot about `ns()` in two `uiOutput`s.
3. And the last thing is usage of `session$ns()`. To be honest, I can't say, why it is necessary (I rather feel that it shouldn't be so easy to just use `inputId` as a string only), however I saw today somewhere in SO similar problem and there solution was to use `session$ns()` so I tried this here. If I would guess, it is because (1) in server part you need `session$ns()` if you want to use `ns()`, i.e. you can't use just `ns()` (hard to say, why); (2) you need `ns()` because you are working with module - think of it that in module whenever you create `ui` you need to use `ns()`, so you should also use `ns()` if you create `ui` in `server` function. **Maybe someone else come here and explain it better.**

Comment: your answers are great based on those I m trying to improve it  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70565573/display-two-visualizations-that-are-based-on-two-different-dataframes-in-modular